# VBA excel code for copying sheets error

Tags: vba, excel

I want a copier to copy one sheet multiple times. So I have made a week planning for week 1.
And now I want this sheet 51 more times. So the name has to start with a 2 and end with a 52. To make this work for x To y I made the following code:

```
   Sub Copier()
   Dim a As Integer
   Dim b As Integer

   a = InputBox("Enter begin number for making copy's")
   b = InputBox("Enter end number for making copy's")

   For x = a To b
      'Loop to make x number copies.
      ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy _
         Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("x")
         'The name of every copied sheet is a number.
   Next
End Sub
```

When I execute this, it gives an error : "Error 9 during executing. The subscript is out of range." (I translated it because I have Dutch Excel.)

I don't see what is wrong because this code is copied from the Microsoft page.
Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2):

```
Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("x")
```

this is looking for a sheet named "x". You may have intended `Sheets(x)`, which refers to a worksheet by its Index number. However, this won't name the sheet - you don't have this code yet.

Comment: Thanks I did not understand that they meant the name of the sheet they want to copy. Do you know how i can get the index of the sheet with as input name of it?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("x")` with `Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(CStr(x))`

`Sheets("x")` whould look for sheet named exactly "x"

`Sheets(x)`, if x is not string type, whould look for sheet with index x

`Sheets(CStr(x))`, ensures your looking for sheet named x.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you used "x" which is a string. If you want to use x as an index you need to use it without the quotation marks.

**Edit**

Using x as a sheet index:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(x)
```

Using the name of a sheet to get its index:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets("Sheet1").Index)
```

Using the number of sheets as the index:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

If you are trying to change the name of the sheet after you copy it you need to add code that does this.

Example:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = x
```

Comment: Ripster this does not work. Because Sheets(x) refers to the index of the sheet like Andy G said. These index has to be the index of the heet I want to copy. I thought more of          Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
         ActiveSheet.Name = "x" but thsi does not work

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish is unclear. Andy G and I said the exact same thing.. I'll update my code to try and explain what I think you are asking but again, it is fairly unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

What I trying to accomplish was this:

```
Sub Copier()
   Dim a As Integer
   Dim b As Integer
   Dim c As String

   c = InputBox("Name of Sheet")
   a = InputBox("Enter begin number for making copy's")
   b = InputBox("Enter end number for making copy's")


   For x = a To b
      'Loop to make x number copies.
      ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy _
         Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(c)


   Next
End Sub
```

The only thing i now still want is that the name of the copied sheet become's x.

Answer (score 0):

This macro will copy sheet "1" to sheets "2" to whatever....

```
Option Explicit

Sub MakeExtraWeeks()
Dim q As Long
Dim i As Long

q = InputBox("How Many extra weeks?")

For i = 2 To q
    Worksheets("1").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = CStr(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

I copy `After:=` the final sheet, so I know exactly where to find the sheet, so I can rename it in the next line (remember that the count of sheets will have increased by 1, so the `.Name` will rename the final sheet)